Application Insights - KQL order by not working when converting to double
I'm trying to write a query in Application Insights to order the results by a property.
I can reproduce it with a datatable like this
datatable(operation_Id: string, timestamp: datetime, name: string, RequestCharge: string, duration: int)
[
    "id_1", datetime(2023-09-14T01:00:00), "operation_1", "45.50", 300,
    "id_2", datetime(2023-09-14T02:00:00), "operation_2", "0.0", 150,
    "id_3", datetime(2023-09-14T03:00:00), "operation_3", "78.23", 550,
    "id_4", datetime(2023-09-14T04:00:00), "operation_4", "32.10", 400,
    "id_5", datetime(2023-09-14T05:00:00), "operation_5", "10.25", 350,
    "id_6", datetime(2023-09-14T06:00:00), "operation_6", "90.85", 450
]
| project operation_Id, timestamp, name, RequestCharge = todouble(trim(" ", RequestCharge)), duration
| where isnotnull(RequestCharge)
| order by RequestCharge desc

Notice the results are not in descending order of RequestCharge

What's really weird, is even if I made the 'source' a decimal, the order is still not working:

datatable(operation_Id: string, timestamp: datetime, name: string, RequestCharge: double, duration: int)
[
    "id_1", datetime(2023-09-14T01:00:00), "operation_1", 45.50, 300,
    "id_2", datetime(2023-09-14T02:00:00), "operation_2", 0.0, 150,
    "id_3", datetime(2023-09-14T03:00:00), "operation_3", 78.23, 550,
    "id_4", datetime(2023-09-14T04:00:00), "operation_4", 32.10, 400,
    "id_5", datetime(2023-09-14T05:00:00), "operation_5", 10.25, 350,
    "id_6", datetime(2023-09-14T06:00:00), "operation_6", 90.85, 450
]
| project operation_Id, timestamp, name, RequestCharge, duration
| where isnotnull(RequestCharge)
| order by RequestCharge desc



I hate to tell you but I can't reproduce your problem. I am seeing a consistent right ordering on multiple runs for both queries.
EDIT
Found the issue: as you can see the sort indicator on the timestamp column indicates you have manually overriden the way the results are sorted:


Oh, wow.... that's embarrassing
Terrible UX though : Tthe 'manual override' doesn't disappear between runs! How confusing
Many thanks for the second pair of eyes on this

You're welcome, we all have these moments
